# Keep state of statefull widget that is inside a bloc builder

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a statefull widget that is inside a bloc builder, my question is if there is anyway I can keep the state of the widget between rebuilds? Because every time the bloc builder is triggered the statefull widget state is being reseted.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`.

Use it with your state class.
You will have to override `wantKeepAlive` method in your state class.
return `true` in your case.

Example would be

```
class _FooWidgetState extends State<FooWidget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    // your build method
  }
  
  @override
  bool wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Great, but seems a detail is missing: `super.build(context)`. I tried your solution I didn't work because of it.

Comment: Does not work in my case